# How do I set `skip` (offset) for reactivemongo mongodb driver?

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I need to skip a number of documents (`offset`) from a query, and only return `limit` number of documents that go after. I know the following naive approach:

```
collection.find(BSONDocument())
  .cursor[T].collect[List](offset+limit).map(_.drop(offset))
```

but it is not really desired because it will load `offset+limit` number of documents in JVM memory, whereas I'd like to filter them on the "database" side.

Answer (score 6):

Solution: use `QueryOpts`. Example:

```
collection.find(BSONDocument())
  .options(QueryOpts(skipN = offset))
  .cursor[T].collect[List](limit)
```

Note that using `skip` is not very efficient because `mongodb` does not support effective pagination, it will just skip the desired number by iterating through all the documents.

Answer (score 2):

VasyaNovikov answer is certainly correct. Reactive mongo offers a more intuitive API:

```
collection.find(BSONDocument())
  .skip(offset)
  .cursor[T]
  .collect[List](limit, Cursor.FailOnError[List[T]]())
```